# Activating Windows 10 in a script?

Tags: powershell

```
$computer = gc env:computername
$key = "WINDOWS CODE EDITED OUT"
$service = get-wmiObject -query "select * from SoftwareLicensingService" -computername $computer
$service.InstallProductKey($key)
$service.RefreshLicenseStatus()
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to Continue"
```

I am trying to get Windows to activate via a PowerShell script, and it doesn't work. This is the error I get:

```
Exception calling "InstallProductKey" : ""
At line:4 char:1
+ $service.InstallProductKey($key)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WMIMethodException
```

Just wondering what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running this from an elevated PowerShell session?  What's the format of the key you're using (with or without hyphens)?

Comment: Related/Possible duplicates: [How do I get an error reason from InstallProductKey (SoftwareLicensingService) in PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8525758/150605), [WMIMethodException with .InstallProductKey](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41292734/150605)

Comment: @BACON I am running in an elevated powershell session, and the format of the key used is hyphen-separated